# automatic GWT ensureDebugId() for every UiField in View?

Tags: gwt, testing, ui-automation

We have quite large application in GWT, and now in order to run automatic tests, we need id's in HTML. 
Say

@UiField
InlineLabel label1;

then in View constructor, we can call

label1.ensureDebugId("label1");

So test scripts can find our label by id.

But, adding this code in every View can be quite annoying if you have 500 @UiFields.

Does GWT deliver some feature to automate this process ?  I'm thinking about some kind of flag which turns on id's everywhere.